# Analog and digital cable encoding

Tags: signal, tv

I am looking to have a card encode multiple channels on to a single cable tv line so that several tv's in the house could change channels to a different stream from the same source like how a cable box can tune in to 1 channel or another from the cable company.  Any one seen such an animal or know if it is possible to get 3 or 4 single channel units that could all be teamed together running on ch 3/4/5... through a cable distrobution unit so that all 3 would be live on the tv side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to combine the outputs of multiple RF modulators, at least if they are reasonably well behaved sources.  The typical CATV splitters you can buy work tolerably well in the other direction as combiners, too.

Comment: any info on the rf modulators for the signal generation side?  I have seen some bits here and there for the recieving side but never found much for generating.  I dont have the best of luck with search tearms and keyword so i find all the wierd stuff and often not the simple stuff.

Comment: actually just rf modulators is a great help so far. now to see if I can find one that does digital cable to.

Comment: A digital cable modulator is likely to be rather expensive; in addition to modulation it's a real time mpeg encoder, not the simple analog circuit that an analog modulator is.